# Generate a matrix where the sum of rows and columns and diagonals is equal

Tags: python, numpy, sudoku

I am trying to get simulate a variation of a Magic Square. I want to randomly generate 3x3 matrices where the sum of rows and columns and diagonals are equal. I also want to know how many solutions exist. This is what I have so far

```
import numpy as np  

r_array = np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 10), size=(3, 3), replace=False)  # ndarray
print(r_array)

rows = len(r_array);  
cols = len(r_array[0]);

for i in range(0, rows):  
    sumRow = 0;  
    for j in range(0, cols):  
        sumRow = sumRow + r_array[i][j];  
    print("Sum of " + str(i+1) +" row: " + str(sumRow));  
for i in range(0, rows):  
    sumCol = 0;  
    for j in range(0, cols):  
        sumCol = sumCol + r_array[j][i];  
    print("Sum of " + str(i+1) +" column: " + str(sumCol));  

def printDiagonalSums(mat, n):
 
    diag1 = 0
    diag2 = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        diag1 += r_array[i][i]
        diag2 += r_array[i][n - i - 1]
         
    print("Sum of Diagonal 1:", diag1)
    print("Sum of Diagonal 2:", diag2)
 
# Driver code
printDiagonalSums(r_array, 3)
```

Comment: What you're trying to build is called a [magic square](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicSquare.html)

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks!

Comment: If you want to find all the possible solutions, there is no reason to use `choice`...

Answer (score 0):

There is only one 3 order magic square (apart from symetries and rotations).

Demo:

The sum of all numbers from 1 to 9 is 45. That means that each row, column or diagonal must sum to 15. Let us considere 1. We have to find pairs summing up to 14: 9 + 5 or 6 + 8. As only 2 pairs are available, the 1 cannot be on a corner (would require 3) or in the middle (would require 4). For the very same reason, 9 cannot be on a corner nor in the middle (6 can only be 4+2 or 5+1)

So we now that one central column (or row  if we rotate) can only be  1-5-9 (or 9-5-1 if we use a symetry). BTW we have just established that the central value was 5. The row containing the 1 can only be 6-1-8 (or 8-1-6 with a symetry). That is enough to compute the 2 other corners (resp 2 and 4) because the sum of the diagonals is 15. And we get the last two values  (7 and 3). So the only possible 3x3 magic square (except for symetries and rotations) is:

```
6 1 8
7 5 3
2 9 4
```

If you want all the possible results including rotations and symetries, there are 4 ways to place the 1 and for each 2 ways to place the 6. So it gives 8 total possibilities.

Here is a possible code that computes those 8 possibilities:

```
# Magic square 3x3

numbers = list(range(1,10))  # number from 1 to 9

rowsum = sum(numbers) // 3   # sum of each row, column or diagonal

table = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]  # an empty 3x3 array

results = []

# compute the possible triples summing to 15 indexed by first value
rows = {}
for i in numbers:
     pairs = []
     rows[i] = pairs
     for j in numbers:
          if j == i:
               continue
          k = rowsum - i - j
          if j < k <= 9 and k != i:
               pairs.append((j,k))
               
# auxiliary functions

# add the first column when we have a top row
def add_col(i, row):
     for col in rows[i]:
          if col is row:
               continue
          table[1][0], table[2][0] = col
          add_diag(i, row, col)
          table[1][0], table[2][0] = reversed(col)
          add_diag(i, row, col)

# add the first diagonal when we have the top row and first column
def add_diag(i, row, col):
     for diag in rows[i]:
          if diag in (row, col):
               continue
          table[1][1], table[2][2] = diag
          valid()
          table[1][1], table[2][2] = reversed(diag)
          valid()
          
# control that the second row, second column and second diagonal are valid
def valid():
     if table[1][1] not in (k for row in rows[table[0][1]] for k in row):
          return
     if table[1][1] not in (k for row in rows[table[1][0]] for k in row):
          return
     table[1][2] = rowsum - table[1][0] - table[1][1]
     table[2][1] = rowsum - table[0][1] - table[1][1]
     if rowsum != sum(table[i][2] for i in range(3)):
          return
     if rowsum != sum(table[2][i] for i in range(3)):
          return
     if rowsum != sum(table[i][2-i] for i in range(3)):
          return
     results.append(tuple(tuple(row) for row in table))

# let us go...     
for i in numbers:
     if len(rows[i]) < 3:    # NW corner: 1 row, 1 column, 1 diagonal
          continue
     table[0][0] = i
     for row in rows[i]:
          table[0][1:] = row
          add_col(i, row)
          table[0][2], table[0][1] = row
          add_col(i, row)
```

Results contains as expected:

```
[((2, 9, 4), (7, 5, 3), (6, 1, 8)),
 ((2, 7, 6), (9, 5, 1), (4, 3, 8)),
 ((4, 9, 2), (3, 5, 7), (8, 1, 6)),
 ((4, 3, 8), (9, 5, 1), (2, 7, 6)),
 ((6, 1, 8), (7, 5, 3), (2, 9, 4)),
 ((6, 7, 2), (1, 5, 9), (8, 3, 4)),
 ((8, 1, 6), (3, 5, 7), (4, 9, 2)),
 ((8, 3, 4), (1, 5, 9), (6, 7, 2))]
```

Comment: Yes, I understood. Also, you said the choice will give me only 1 solution. How do I print all the symetries and rotations of the magic square?

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful! Still a novice at Python, so I need quite some help with easy coding as well